# Проверка contact us

Tags: javascript, html, css

В процессе освоения `js` решил по практиковаться, поэтому в ходе работы возникли следующие некоторые вопросы:
Хотелось бы услышать что лучше убрать вообще, а что оставить.
А если конкретнее, то как лучше оптимизировать код, не вписывая каждый раз в ветке `else` старые значения `input`, см. код:

```js
(function() {

  function checkMailOrMessage() {

    this.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      enter = this.value;
      type = this.type;
      leng = enter.length;
      if (leng < 5 && type == 'text') { //for name
        thumbUp.style.opacity = '1';
        label[0].style.color = "red";
        thumbUp.style.top = '73' + 'px'
        label[0].textContent = "Имя > 5 символов";

      } else if (leng < 5 && type == 'email') { // for e-mail
        thumbUp.style.opacity = '1';
        thumbUp.style.top = '178' + 'px'
        label[1].style.color = "red";
        label[1].textContent = "Email более 5 символов";
      } else { // reset
        thumbUp.style.opacity = '0';
        label[0].style.color = "#d3d3d3";
        label[1].style.color = "#d3d3d3";
        label[0].textContent = "Email";
        label[1].textContent = "Message";
      }
    });
  };
  let thumbUp = document.getElementById('check'),
    label = document.getElementsByTagName('label'),
    name = document.getElementById('contact-body');
  name.addEventListener('click', function(e) { /*is input?*/
    if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') {
      checkMailOrMessage.call(e.target)

    }

  });


}())
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #a5debf;
}

input:valid,
input:invalid {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

textarea,
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

label {
  color: #d3d3d3;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

label:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

label:first-child::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f2c0';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.contact-body label:nth-child(3)::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f129';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.contact-body label:nth-child(5)::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f2bc';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.bg-contact {
  height: 240px;
  width: 470px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(#284550, #1c3645, #152d3b, #0a1f30);
  position: relative;
}

.contact {
  width: 330px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact-title {
  background: #7781cf;
  color: white;
  padding: 70px 0 25px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.contact-title h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.contact-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
  padding: 35px 25px 70px 25px;
  position: relative
}

.contact-body input,
textarea {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

.tabs {
  position: absolute;
  right: 27px;
  top: 30px;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #7781cf;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  opacity: .6;
}

.circle i {
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  right: 3px;
  color: white;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-59deg);
  top: 10px;
}

.circle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  right: 43px;
  top: 77px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.check::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f087";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-contact">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="circle" id="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <div class="contact-title">
        <h3>Contact us</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-body" id="contact-body">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
        <label for="">Message</label>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Your Massage"></textarea>
        <span id="check" class="check"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="<script src=" https://use.fontawesome.com/23797a88dd.js></script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waytogojunior/hpkrhnqr/)

Comment: Для того, что бы к каждому элементу не держать его значение в js. Предлагаю прописать каждому элементу атрибут `data-default=""` И указать в нём значение по умолчанию. А в js, при восстановлении значений, брать их из этих атрибутов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я расскажу об основных улучшениях и покажу пример, но упрощу HTML и CSS, чтобы было проще.

1. Нужно использовать тег `form`. Вы не сможете отправить форму без этого тега.
2. Обязательные для заполнения поля можно определить с помощью атрибута `required`.
3. Ошибки лучше оформлять с помощью CSS, навешивая дополнительный класс.
4. Есть смысл использовать маленькие функции, а не одну большую портянку. Так код легче поддерживать и изменять.
5. Как сказал vihtor лучше использовать data-атрибут для хранения стандартного значения имени, чтобы не приходилось при добавлении нового поля добавлять еще одну конструкцию с `if` в ваш JavaScrip код.
6. Вы навешиваете слушателя для события `blur` на инпуте только после клика по контейнеру. Этого события может если, например, пользователь придет в форму с помощью таба. Вообще использовать `click` в таких случаях очень плохая идея. Когда дальше вы будете писать обработчик для формы, то вешайте слушателя на `change` у формы, а не на `click` у кнопки.
7. Я убрал из своего примера обертку в виде анонимной самовызывающейся функции `(function() {})();`, но сделал это только для того, чтобы избежать дополнительной табуляции в примере. Вообще это стоит использовать, но, вообще, я бы советовал использовать [классы](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class), чтобы можно было переиспользовать этот код, когда нужно будет работать с другой формой.

Вот пример, как можно было подойти к задаче:

```js
// Сохраняем ссылку на форму в переменную
const form = document.querySelector('form');

// Получаем все поля
const fields = Array.from(form.elements);

// Переберем их
fields.forEach(field => {
  // Если поле не обязательное, то просто ничего не делаем
  if(!field.required) return;
  
  // А если обязательное, то добавляем обработчик на потерю фокуса
  field.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    // В функцию-обработчик передаем поле
    checkField(field);
  });
});

// Проверяет валидно ли поле и выводит ошибки
function checkField(field) {
  // Проверемя валидно ли поле
  const isValid = validField(field);
  
  // Показываем или скрываем ошибку в зависимости от валидности
  toggleError(field, isValid) 
}

// Функция переключает видимость ошибки в зависимости от переданного второго параметра
function toggleError(field, isValid) {
  // Получаем родителя
  // Если нужна поддержка IE, то нужно добавить полифилл для closest
  // https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest
  const parent = field.closest('.field');
  
  // Лейбл
  const label = parent.querySelector('label');
  
  // Сохраняем знанчение по умолчанию, чтобы потом его вернуть,
  // но делаем это только если мы его не сохранили раньше
  if(!label.dataset.default) {
    label.setAttribute('data-default', label.textContent);
  }
  
  // В зависимости от переднного значения isError выводим либо ошибку, либо стандартное значение
  label.textContent = isValid ? label.dataset.default : label.dataset.error;
  
  // Меняем класс, отвечающий за оформление ошибки
  parent.classList.toggle('error', !isValid);
}


// Проверяет валидно ли поле
function validField(field) {
  // Если кол-во символов меньше 5, то вернется false
  return field.value.length > 4
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  font: 16px/1.5em sans-serif;
}

.field {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: normal;
}

.field textarea,
.field input {
  width: 100%;
  font: 16px/1.5em sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.field.error textarea,
.field.error input {
  border-color: red; 
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.field.error:after,
.field.error:after {
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  right: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.field.error label {
  color: red;
}

button {
  font: 16px/1.5em sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form novalidate>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name" data-error="Имя должно быть длинее 5 символов">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Имя" required>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name" data-error="Эл. почта должна быть длинее 5 символов">Эл. почта</label>
    <input type="email" id="name" placeholder="Эл. почта" required>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name">Сообщение</label>
    <textarea id="name" placeholder="Сообщение" required, rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```